# Compiling Chipmunk with Code::Blocks

Tags: compiler-errors, codeblocks, chipmunk

I seem to be unable to compile chipmunk without compile errors, can anyone help me? I turned on C99 but I still get errors.
Here's a few:

C:\c++\ChipmunkLib\chipmunk.c:70: error: 'M_PI' undeclared (first use in this function)
C:\c++\ChipmunkLib\chipmunk.c:70: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
C:\c++\ChipmunkLib\chipmunk.c:70: error: for each function it appears in.)
C:\c++\ChipmunkLib\chipmunk.c: In function 'cpAreaForSegment':
C:\c++\ChipmunkLib\chipmunk.c:85: error: 'M_PI' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: chipmunk is a C library, just compile it with visual c++ express edition (free) and after that you're free to use any ide / compiler to link with it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use VSC++ static library's with GCC

Comment: Compiled with gnu99 and it worked fine.